# Who am I? (Difficult)

Tags: number-sequence

You lot are geniuses, someone amaze me and work out who I am.

```
-----  -- - 
100000000000
264212623602
426426172659
912984719353
309296113624
443693526391
764459160890
688026684468
000000000000
000000000000
```

Starting point

> The numbers are orientated wrongly, rotate the square

First hurdle

> The numbers are timestamps, what do the dates mean?

Comment: Ah yes, a guess what I'm thinking question labeled "difficult". Perfect.

Comment: Guessing usually isn't a very good way to solve a puzzle. If you can't recognise the formatting of the numbers then there are plenty other puzzles out there for you. The starting point is a pattern that has been in use for more than 40 years and is extremely common

Comment: No useful hints?

Comment: @Techidiot I kinda abandoned this due to the downvotes, assumed nobody was going to try. I'll edit with a hint just for you!

Comment: Would like to try if I can.

Comment: I have converted the date stamps and searched around google. I can't recognize any significance to the dates myself. I am hopeful the correct answer will show that there was a nice path to the answer that I missed.

Comment: @Ryan27 You might want to post your work as a Partial Answer if you think it's meaningful.  Might prod someone else to be able to move forward.

Comment: Interesting that both answers so far have made the same incorrect assumption about a key part of the rotation and that error has sent them down the wrong path

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer :
rotating the rectangle anticlockwise and converting numbers obtained as unix timestamp leads me to those dates (I kept the pipes in front) :

- 1979-04-20 01:00:00
- | 1971-10-03 02:00:00
- 1991-01-12 01:00:00
- | 1980-06-09 03:00:00
- | 1978-08-05 03:00:00
- 1989-07-23 01:00:00
- 1978-05-22 01:00:00
- | 1974-02-02 01:00:00
- | 1977-11-25 01:00:00
- | 1984-09-02 03:00:00
- | 1989-09-06 03:00:00
- | 2009-08-04 03:00:00

Note sure for the hours, as it may depend of local time....

The same list, using UTC timestamp :

- 1979-04-19 23:00:00
- | 1971-10-03 01:00:00
- 1991-01-12 00:00:00
- | 1980-06-09 01:00:00
- | 1978-08-05 01:00:00
- 1989-07-22 23:00:00
- 1978-05-21 23:00:00
- | 1974-02-02 00:00:00
- | 1977-11-25 00:00:00
- | 1984-09-02 01:00:00
- | 1989-09-06 01:00:00
- | 2009-08-04 01:00:00

Comment: I was thinking since we are looking for a 'who' the earliest date may be a birth date?

Comment: @Ryan27 Tried that, and also last date as a death date, but nothing came from my research that can link other dates of the list.

Comment: The times are interesting. There has to be something to the fact that they are all one of those 3 times. Hmm, what event always occurs at one of those 3 times of day?

Comment: @Ryan27 I thought that it could be a hint about the timezone, but it would have been only two different hours for winter/summer cycle. Three different hours, it is strange.

Answer (score 1):

```
1979-04-20 01:00:00
| 1971-10-03 02:00:00
1991-01-12 01:00:00
| 1980-06-09 03:00:00
| 1978-08-05 03:00:00
1989-07-23 01:00:00
1978-05-22 01:00:00
| 1974-02-02 01:00:00
| 1977-11-25 01:00:00
| 1984-09-02 03:00:00
| 1989-09-06 03:00:00
| 2009-08-04 03:00:00
```

My analysis:
These dates seem to be taken at 03:00, 01:00, or 02:200
If you take away the month from the day; you get the hour at which it is at.
All I have for now.
This doesn't seem to work for all. Maybe a coincidence?
eg 1989-09-06 03:00. Take way 6 from 9 and you get 3. Partial Answer. Thanks to Xoff for the dates.

The hours of these dates are in the witching hour, too. 
Could be related?

If you take the UTC timestamps

```
1979-04-19 23:00:00
| 1971-10-03 01:00:00
1991-01-12 00:00:00
| 1980-06-09 01:00:00
| 1978-08-05 01:00:00
1989-07-22 23:00:00
1978-05-21 23:00:00
| 1974-02-02 00:00:00
| 1977-11-25 00:00:00
| 1984-09-02 01:00:00
| 1989-09-06 01:00:00
| 2009-08-04 01:00:00
```

also from Xoff, some start to match up, again.
For example, 2009 (take the 9) and 08 (take the 8) from 2009-08-04 and subtract them, you get 1. Yet again this is the hour.
In the case of     1979-04-19 23:00:00; you can do the month + the day. Which again brings you to the hour. The hour seems to be important.

Thanks to Xoff.
These dates seem to be death dates of famous music, movie people.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: If we rotate also the '|', and take it for a minus sign, we get these dates:

```
Fri, 30 May 1930 23:00:00 GMT
Thu, 27 Apr 1950 23:00:00 GMT
Sun, 01 May 1955 23:00:00 GMT
Wed, 07 Feb 1962 00:00:00 GMT
Tue, 30 Nov 1965 00:00:00 GMT
Sun, 21 May 1978 23:00:00 GMT
Sat, 22 Jul 1989 23:00:00 GMT
Mon, 29 May 1961 23:00:00 GMT
Sat, 25 Jul 1959 23:00:00 GMT
Sat, 12 Jan 1991 00:00:00 GMT
Sun, 31 Mar 1968 23:00:00 GMT
Thu, 19 Apr 1979 23:00:00 GMT
```

I tried reading the years as ASCII codes, yielding

> 27>ANY=;[DO, (the first character (30=RS) is unwritable)

This still makes no sense to me.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, and the first date is Clint Eastwood birth, but can't find a link with other dates...